# Overlapping sound in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been looking a whole day on the internet for a answer to my question if i can overlapp one sound over the same one...

I am making a jet and when it fires a bullet my sound plays (it is something like 3 sec long track, so pretty long) and my next sound is after the whole track finishes... Is there any way to overlapp the same track over the previous ones?

my code is really simple just 
`var sound = new Audio(); 
sound.src = audio/audio.mp3`
 and where my jet fires i have a simple `sound.play();` statement...
i hope it is possible to overlapp the same sound in Javascript.. thank you

(i am a very beginner to Javascript:) )

Comment: Browser support here varies.  Some browsers will play multiple sounds at once, others won't.  In any case, you should have multiples of the same object for best luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the API allows you to use the sound output twice in the same process... But you can try, use a [Timing event](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) to delay the play.